# Difference between AEM, Contentful and Strapi CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, aem, strapi, contentful

what are the main differences between Adobe Experience Manager, Contentful and Strapi CMS regarding  features from a content creater perspective? As well as over all? I’ve been searching a lot and I mostly found out about pricing and implementation stuff. I want to know, when the CMS already is in place, which is most sutable for a company who only needs to add/edit content and what are the difference in each feautures/dashboard functions?

Searched online a lot as well as contacted each CMS distributer.